# Nginx resolving system in Docker container

Tags: nginx, docker, resolve

I got strange situation with Nginx in the Docker.

I have 3 containers that run as a services in the Docker swarm.

Docker version is: `17.03.1-ce, build c6d412e.`

Docker command to run swarm is: `docker deploy -c docker-compose.yml synergy`

Docker compose file is here: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sodrian/synergy/master/docker-compose.yml

The strange thing is as follows:

If I use 80 port nginx server directives similar to this ones, everything is ok:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name SOME_NAME.com;
    location / {
        uwsgi_pass synergy_uwsgi:8001;
        include uwsgi_params;
    }
}
```

If 443 directives are used I keep getting the error:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name SOME_NAME.com;
    ssl_certificate SOME_PATH;
    ssl_certificate_key SOME_OTHER_PATH;

    location / {
        uwsgi_pass synergy_uwsgi:8001;
        include uwsgi_params;
    }
}
```

The Nginx error: `host not found in upstream "synergy_uwsgi"`

I had to write the script

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sodrian/synergy/master/deploy/nginx/synergy_uwsgi_resolve.sh

and change CMD on nginx container to:

`CMD sh /etc/nginx/synergy_uwsgi_resolve.sh && nginx -g "daemon off;"`

to make it run.

So the question is: why can nslookup resolve synergy_uwsgi host, but nginx can't?

Comment: maybe the underscore in synergy_uwsgi? It could be a bug in uwsgi

Comment: it works for 80 port, so it can't be bug for uwsgi. moreover the nginx is complaining.

Comment: it's true, you're right

Comment: are you sure that this was not a temporary dns fail resolution?

Comment: i try to run nginx as a docker service, so if it fails on startup it reloads every 5 seconds.

Comment: I suspect it could be a timing issue; when using a certificate, nginx may do a lookup directly when starting nginx, to resolve the domain name associated with the certificate. When not using TLS, the service is not looked up until the first request comes in (just thinking out loud, not sure if it's the case)

Comment: @thaJeztah Nginx resolves all of its upstream DNS names at the startup. It's not a lazy task

Comment: yes, it's clean that nginx resolves all upstream. the problem is why nslookup can resolve synergy_uwsgi domain, but nginx can't.